# Facing "Problem of parsing the package" while installing a wrapped APK file with Microsoft Intune in android phone

Tags: android, intune

I have an APK file which is installing and working fine on android phone, but when I am wrapping this APK file with Microsoft Intune it is giving an error  when I try to install this wrapped APK file.

> There was a problem parsing the package

steps I followed during wrapping:

1. `Import-Module .\IntuneAppWrappingTool.psm1`
2. `Invoke-AppWrappingTool -InputPath .\new\app-release1.apk -OutputPath .\newtry\wrapped.apk -KeyStorePath .\key\upload-keystore.jks -Verbose`
3. It gives wrapped-unsigned.apk at OutputPath (with message that intune can not sign the apk because targeting API level is 30 or above and some v1 type problem was there)

   Now when I tried to install this file I got the same error as facing above then I signed this wrapped unsigned file
4. Signed wrapped apk file by Android apksigner

now again I tried to install my wrapped and signed apk file but I am facing the same error again

I am not able to understand where the things happening wrong. I am providing a signed APK file to InputPath of of Intune

How can I wrap my APK file correctly so that it can run properly?

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to perform zipalign command before signing again:

```
zipalign -p -f -v 4 infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Also make sure that you uninstalled an old app from device.